# How to do an optimization of a for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, optimization

I have this part of code which is very long to run and I would like to know if it is possible to do an optimization or a vectorization for a faster running?

```
if intersect(pt, coord,'rows')                    
  for t=1:size(pt,1)
    for u=1:size(Mbb,1)
      if  pt(t,1)==Mbb(u,1)
        img(pt(t,1),Mbb(u,2))=1;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you better provide data for help

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ set of sample data that everybody can use to run your code.

Comment: Sorted?  Repeated values of Mbb(:,1)?  Repeated values in pt(:,1)?  Presumably integer-valued and strictly positive?  And presumably the range isn't huge since you're indexing an image?  It looks like we can leave out the `coord` intersection as that doesn't interact with the loop.

Comment: You could have looked for 0-distances using `pdist2`, then use that as a logical index. No looping required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try multi-threading. Even on a single core multi-threading may increase the efficiency of your core. If you have a multi-core system then multi-threading will yield even more benefit. In MATLAB this is done using parfor. Note that this can only be done when there is no dependencies between loop iteration. Your code will have to look something like this. Sometimes the MATLAB interpreter will be over conservative in detecting dependencies and hence you have to write your loops in such a way that the interpreter doesnt see dependencies in iterations

```
if intersect(pt, coord,'rows') 
  loopsize=size(pt,1);                   
  parfor t=1:loopsize
    for u=1:size(Mbb,1)
      if  pt(t,1)==Mbb(u,1)
        img(pt(t,1),Mbb(u,2))=1;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There is a better way to do this than to use `parfor`.  Also you need the parallel computing toolbox if you want to use `parfor`.

Answer (score 0):

You spend much time comparing `pt(t,1)` and `Mbb(u,1)` to find matches, in a double loop. If the respective sizes are large, this can be costly (`O(NM)`).

What you can do is to pre-sort these arrays and search for equal values by a merge-like process, taking only `O(N+M)` operations.

---

Anyway, note that if the arrays `pt` and `Mbb` include many equal elements, which are also equal between the arrays, the problem can degenerate to `NM` matches. In this case, the sorting trick can't help.